# Pagination with dynamic data tables using jquery plugin and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, postgresql, pagination

I'm trying to paginate my dynamic data table from postgresql database. The data gets loaded onto the page but when it does, the pagination doesn't work. Also if I put static data, it works.

I'm using jquery plugins jquery.js and jquery.dataTables.js

I think my jquery code is not getting the table, not sure

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "itemsOnPage": 8,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "bFilter": true
            }
            );
        } );
    </script>
```

and here's my table

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="example">
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th width="6%"><strong>col1</strong></th>
       <th width="20%"><strong>col2</strong></th>
       <th width="30%"><strong>col3</strong></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="selects">
     <?php
      $count=0;
      while($row=pg_fetch_array($result))
      {?>
     <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['col1']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $name =$row['col2']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $type =$row['col3']; ?></td>
     <?php $count=$count++; ?>
     </tr>
    <?php  }
   ?>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: you have to call $('#example').dataTable() after php has created the table information

Comment: it is being called after the creation of table info, still not working
any ideas?

Comment: Please some one help me out! I would be really thankful

Answer (score 0):

You must change `$('#example').dataTable()` for  `$('#example').DataTable()`, thats it.